# Carregar combobox com dados de $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

Estou fazendo um método que vai no BD faz uma *query* e retorna os códigos.

Com esses códigos eu carrego a `Combobox` com os respectivos itens.

Tem vezes que preenche certinho, tem vezes que não preenche... Alguma ideia?

```
$.getJSON("carrega.php?id_usuario=" + id_usuario + "&id_cord=" + id_cordao,function(data){
    $.each(data.cord, function(i,user){         
        //Carrega o Combo com o Valor do BD
        $('#cbo1').val(user.cord1);
        $('#cbo2').val(user.cord2);
        $('#cbo3').val(user.cord3);
        $('#cbo4').val(user.cord4);                 
    }); 
});
```

Engraçado é que quando eu coloco um `alert` antes de preencher o *Combo*, ele funciona :)

Comment: Coloca o teu HTML e o que vem nesse JSON senão fica dificil de ajudar. Tentando adivinhar, talvez isto te ajude? http://jsfiddle.net/0pdxwhx0/

Comment: Ao invés de colocar um alert, use o `console.log(...)`. Dessa maneira fica mais fácil entender o que houve pois o problema de sincronismo continuará ocorrendo. Além disso, você poderia usar promisses e imprimir os resultados nos eventos de `done`, `fail` e `always`.

Comment: Ola Eduardo! A funcao toda eh isso ai...ele retorna 5 campos do php...O que eu percebo eh que ele traz certinho os dados, mas da esses bugs na hora de preencher o .val

Comment: e cara, nao entendi muito bem o q vc respondeu...mas vc falou certo..eh algum problema de sincronismo...

Comment: @RafaelSpessotto o que dá `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` se colocares antes do `$.each`?

Comment: Sergio ele retorna normal os dados do BD...mas nao preenche o combo com essas informacoes... :(

Comment: @RafaelSpessotto podes mostrar aqui o que dá o `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`? não faço ideia de como o teu JSON é, e vendo-o a coisa fica mais fácil.

Answer (score 1):

Fala Rafael,

Quando você utiliza `.val(valor)` em um *combo box*, você na realidade está selecionando um item existente no *box*.

Para popular um *combo box* através de resultados do banco de dados, você pode fazer isso:

```js
var frutas = ['maca','pera','uva'];

var _htmlOptions = "";
$.each(frutas,function(i,fruta){
   _htmlOptions += "<option val='"+fruta+"'>"+fruta+"</option>";
});

$("#comboFrutas").append(_htmlOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="comboFrutas"></select>
```

Comment: Fala Gustavo! Obrigado pela resposta....Mas o combo esta preenchido anteriormente sim..eu tneho uma rotina que preenche ele...O Problema esta em justamente eu conseguir preencher o combo, com o ID do item que veio do BD.. Exemplo: ID 2 ITEM: RAFAEL... Eu vou no BD, pego o valor 2, e quero que o combo fique com o valor "RAFAEL", entao eu uso o .val...so que quando eu executo no browser, ele da algum problema, pois tem horas que ele muda o valor para "RAFAEL" e horas que ele nao faz nada e fica no primeiro item adicionado..

Comment: Entendi, para conseguirmos te ajudar, precisamos saber o que está retornando na variável data;

Pelo que eu vi, para cada usuário dentro de data.cord, você está modificando o valor do combo, é isso mesmo?

Comment: {"cord":[{"ID":"8","ID_USUARIO":"2","ID_CORD":"1","ESP1":"63","ESP2":"104","ESP3":"105","ESP4":"106","ESP5":"0","ESP6":"0"}]}

Comment: Esse é o retorno Gustavo... Obrigado pela ajuda!